# Does websockets work with tomcat7 on cloudbees?

Tags: websocket, tomcat7, cloudbees

Cloudbees now support websockets : http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/WebSockets

I tried to implement a very simple test on cloudbees using the tomcat7 clickStack

You can see the webpage trying to open this websocket here : http://wstest.ws.cloudbe.es/

This is working on my machine but doesn't at RUN@cloud

Am I missing something? The tomcat7 clickStack doesn't support websockets?

Thanks in advance.

My Servlet :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.catalina.websocket.MessageInbound;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/testWebsocket")
public class TestWebsocket extends WebSocketServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String string, HttpServletRequest hsr) {
        return new MessageInbound() {
            @Override
            protected void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound) {
                super.onOpen(outbound);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onClose(int status) {
                super.onClose(status);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBinaryMessage(ByteBuffer bb) throws IOException {
            }

            @Override
            protected void onTextMessage(CharBuffer cb) throws IOException {
                System.out.println(cb.toString());
                WsOutbound outbound = getWsOutbound();
                outbound.writeTextMessage(CharBuffer.wrap((cb.toString()).toCharArray()));
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the tomcat version you are using on cloudbees? Note that, WebSocket was available in tomcat with stable version 7.0.42 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this combination, but afaik this should work. Di you well configured your router in http 1.1 mode ?